# prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: node.js, npm

i've installed node js on windows 10 32 bit,
but when i try to type `

> npm -v

there always error message

> 'CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files
>    (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not
>    recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
>    batch file.

what should i do?

`

Answer (score 0):

Try node -v make sure node is installed.
Then command should be `npm install -g your_package`

Comment: what the meaning of your_package ?

Answer (score 0):

You said your Windows is 32-bit, but the error message showed “Program Files (x86)”, which should probably not the intended case, since “Program Files (x86)” should only appears in 64-bit version of Windows; and the 32-bit Windows only contains 1-and-only-1 “Program Files”.

Either the node installer was wrong with the path, or you/your script/npm.cmd, or something similar, has prematurely pointed to wrong location.

If that was really npm.cmd issue, you should report bug to nodejs.

To verify, try this

> cd "C:\Program Files\nodejs"; .\npm -v